# Unable to trigger click function in own custom plugin

Tags: javascript, function, events, addeventlistener, dom-events

I am trying to write  own custom plain Javascript plugin.

Here is my sample plugin code:

```
(function() {
    var pMethods = {
        append: function(text) {
            var node = this.node;
            node.innerHTML += text;
        },
        click: function(fn) {
            if (this.node instanceof Array) {
                this.node.forEach(function(e) {
                    e.addEventListener('click', function() {
                        fn();
                    });
                }, this);
            } else {
                this.node.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                    fn(e);
                });
            }
        }
    };
    myPlugin = function(selector) {
        this.node = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        if (this.node.length === 1) {
            this.node = this.node[0];
        }
        return this.node;
    };
    myPlugin.prototype = pMethods;

    this.r = function(selector) {
        return new myPlugin(selector);
    };
}());
```

which has just two function append and click.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <div class="close"></div>
```

Now I am trying to add click event on close div as follow:

```
r('.close').click(function() {
    alert('Hi')
});
```

but it is not working as expected and I don't know what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code did not work because you were explicitly checking if your element collection is an `Array`. Any element collection returned will be a `NodeList` which is an array like object, but not an array.

```
if (this.node instanceof Array)
```

should be

```
if (this.node instanceof NodeList)
```

Or you could use `Array.prototype.slice` to convert the `NodeList` to an `Array`

```
this.node = Array.prototype.slice.call(
  document.querySelectorAll(selector)
)
```

Here are a couple of optimisations.

```js
(function() {
  var pMethods = {
    append: function(text) {
      // iterate over the collection
      this.nodes.forEach(function(node) {
        node.innerHTML += text;
      })
      // return this for chaining
      return this
    },
    click: function(fn) {
      // iterate over the collection
      this.nodes.forEach(function(e) {
        e.addEventListener('click', fn);
      });
      // return this for chaining
      return this
    },
    find: function(selector) {
      return new myPlugin(
        // flat map over each of the nodes in the collection
        this.nodes.reduce(function(nodes, node) {
          return [].concat.apply(nodes, node.querySelectorAll(selector))
        }, [])
      )
    }
  };
  myPlugin = function(nodes) {
    // changed constructor to recievea array of elemnets only
    // it's private so won't affect anything else
    this.nodes = nodes
  };
  myPlugin.prototype = pMethods;

  this.r = function(selector) {
    var nodes = null
    // handle creating the object with normal elements
    if (selector instanceof HTMLElement) {
      nodes = [selector]
    }
    else {
      nodes = [].slice.call(
        document.querySelectorAll(selector)
      );
    }
    return new myPlugin(nodes);
  };
}());

r('.close')
  .click(function(e) {
    console.log('alerts suck! ' + e.target.textContent)
    r(e.target).find('.child').append(' appended child!')
  })
  .append(' append works!')
```

```html
<div class="close">
  close
  <div class="child">this is the child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I return this its return a myplugin object which is not useful in another javascript plugin which looks for the element

Comment: Hey how to implement find function to find the element within the clicked element on click function 
r('.close').click(function() {
    r(this).find('.menu-item-container');
});

Comment: had to change a couple of things as the previous code only took a selector, now it can take elements or selectors. Then we needed to flatmap the nodes collection to get the children of the selected elements.

Comment: Hey I am trying to implement off function to remove event listener like r('.close').off('click').click(function(){console.log('clicked')})

Comment: because I have r('.close').click(function(){console.log('click‌​ed')}) in some function which is called mutliple time and due to which click get trigged multitple time

Comment: that's much more complicated. jQuery uses it's own pub sub event system to allow it to do that. I recommend that you read "secret's of a javascript ninja" it's by John Resig (the creator of jQuery). He give's readers all the techniques used to construct jQuery. It's one of the top 5 books I have read.

Answer (score 0):

your constructor function (e.g. `myPlugin = function(selector) {`) should return `this` instead of `this.node`